# Add new row by using JavaScript in <div>

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I want to add new row when the button is clicked. Below is my code.

```
<div class="table">
<div id="rows" class="row">

<div id="col1" class="p2">
  <asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server" Text="" TextAlign="Right" />
</div>

<div id="col2" class="p3">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="col3" class="p4">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text="2.00"/>
</div>

<div id="col4"class="p5">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="col5" class="p6">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text="1.00"/>
</div>

<div class="row2" style="text-align:center;">
  <button class="clsButton" id="addrow">Add Row</button>
</div>
</div>
```

below is my jQuery code:

```
 var cloneCount = 1;

    //add new row
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
        $('#rows')
        .clone(true)
        .attr('id', 'rows' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'row')
       .insertAfter('[id^=rows]:last');
        return false;
    });
```

The button does not seems to be working. Which part was wrong? I'm really new in JavaScript. Im using VisualStudio 2012, in .aspx form and C# language. Thanks for helping!

Comment: What are you doing with var obj = `document.getElementById("checkbox3");` even it's not available in youe snippet.

Comment: soryy @surya. My bad. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Hmm, if you are in a need of cloning it, you need to do something like `row1 = row.cloneNode(true);` and then `document.getElementById('table').append(row1);`
But this will lead you to duplicate the IDs. So use classes instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function AddRow() {
    var row = document.getElementById("row1");
    var row1 = row.cloneNode(true);
    var box = document.getElementById("table");
    box.appendChild(row1);
}
```

This is the answer you need I think. But it's not the good practice as you'll be duplicating the IDs here. Use `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: I'd try but it still didnt work. Do I need to change in the css?

Comment: if you are using `document.getElementsByClassName`. It'll return you an array of the elements having the class and `appendChild` works on the element, not the class. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0]` for now.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from JavaScript to jQuery. And the problem were solved. Thanks for helping. below is my answer.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var cloneCount = 1;

    //add new row
    $("#addrow").click(function () {
        $('#row')
        .clone(true)
        .attr('id', 'row' + cloneCount++, 'class', 'row')
       .insertAfter('[id^=row]:last');
        return false;
    });
</script>
```